# Retrieve data from database by java & myphpadmin

Tags: java, database, phpmyadmin

[image]

The user will be asked to enter one `E_Id` (PK) to retrieve the "salary" data of that employee. For example, the **user key in** e.g. 105, it will return the data which is *2600*. What is the query I should write as the user will enter the different PK each time to get different data? I have connected successfully to the myth-admin.

```
SELECT salary FROM Employee WHERE E_ID = ?????? (supposed to be the input of user)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That query looks reasonable (just use `Salary` instead of `salary`) so what's the problem or question?

Comment: Did you create a new user to ask a slightly different question than [this (now deleted) one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66964101/retrieve-certain-data-from-myphpadmin-by-using-java) or is this homework and there's a bunch of new users asking about it? Because if it's the first case, you should just have waited for someone to reopen it, since you modified it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca exactly my thought :)

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way to do this is by using a `JDBC statement`. A basic query would look like following:

```
Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root","root");
Statement statement= conexion.createStatement();
String id="105"; //Here you would need to get the input of the user
String query= "select Salary from Employee where E_ID='"+id+"'";
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(query);
```

Another way more seccure would be using `Prepared Statement` to avoid SQL injection.

```
String query= "select Salary from Employee where E_ID= ? ";
Connection conexion= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/test", "root", "root");
PreparedStatement ps= conexion.prepareStatement(query);
sentencia.setString(1, "105");
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```